# Azure Cache for Redis C# client creating HASH instead of STRING

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis, .net-6.0, azure-redis-cache

I am using .NET 6 to test an Azure Redis connection. However when i use the SetStringAsync it is creating a HASH type entry in Redis. And when i use GetStringAsync to retrieve an existing key that is of type STRING i get "WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value"

Code below is using Linqpad version 7

It is Redis version 4.0.14 in Azure.

I am using the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis package 6.0.1

For connection string i get it from the Access Keys page in Azure:

```
var redisOptions = new RedisCacheOptions();
redisOptions.Configuration = "*********.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=**********,ssl=True,abortConnect=False";
IDistributedCache cache = new RedisCache(redisOptions);

cache.SetStringAsync("This.Is.A.Test.Key","Testing123");
```

This is what the key looks like in Redis Insights:

[image]

And when i try to get a string key/value:

[image]

```
try
{           
    var test = await cache.GetStringAsync("This.Is.A.Test.String.Key"); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: You set "This.Is.A.Test.Key", but you tried to retrieve "This.Is.A.Test.String.Key".

Comment: Yes - these are two different operations i am trying here with two different keys. The first example i am showing what happens when i create a string key - it creates a HASH. The second code block i am showing what happens when i attempt to get existing string key (completely different key) its throwing an exception

Comment: OK, but you're not exactly comparing apples and apples here.  Can you show us your operation where you inserted "This.Is.A.Test.String.Key" into the cache, and what that looked like in Redis Insights?

Comment: I manually inserted the key "This.Is.A.Test.String.Key" into Redis Insights, and then used the code above to try and retrieve it. The second screenshot above shows what the key looks like in Redis Insights

Comment: Are you able to retrieve "This.Is.A.Test.Key"?

Comment: Interestingly yes i am! And it returns it as a string. The problem i have is that i have a lot of existing keys that are STRING type which doesn't work i.e. gets that exception above when trying to retrieve string type.

Comment: Ok, i have found another library that does work as expected: StackExchange.Redis.
IDatabase db;
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("*******.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=*******,ssl=True,abortConnect=False");
db = redis.GetDatabase();

string value = db.StringGet("This.Is.A.Test.String.Key");

Answer (score -3):

In a distributed caching scenario using the `IDistributedCache` interface, the caching mechanism relies on a hashing strategy that takes server names or identifiers into account to evenly distribute cached data across multiple servers or nodes. This approach helps in load balancing and improves scalability in distributed systems.

Let me break down how this works:

**1. IDatabase**: This interface is often associated with a database system like Redis. When you use `IConnectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase()`, you obtain an instance of a database where you can store key-value pairs.

**2. IDistributedCache**: `IDistributedCache` is an abstraction layer built on top of a distributed caching system, commonly used in web applications and microservices to efficiently store and retrieve data across multiple servers.

**3. Hashing and Server Names**: To distribute cached data across servers, a hashing mechanism is employed. This mechanism takes into account the server's name or identifier to ensure that data is evenly distributed and can be efficiently retrieved from the correct server.

- For instance, if you have a server named "fooServer" and use `IDistributedCache` to insert a key-value pair with "TestKey" as the key and "value" as the value, the system generates a hashed key like "fooServerTestKey."
- If you later add another server named "barServer" to the system and it also uses `IDistributedCache` to insert a key-value pair with the same key "TestKey," it would generate a hashed key like "barServerTestKey."

Here's a table illustrating this hashing process:

| Server Name | Key | Hashed Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fooServer | TestKey | fooServerTestKey |
| barServer | TestKey | barServerTestKey |

By employing this approach, the distributed caching system ensures that keys are distributed across servers in a manner that facilitates efficient retrieval. When you need to retrieve the value associated with "TestKey," the system hashes the key to determine which server should hold the data and then retrieves it from that server.

This approach enhances load balancing and scalability because different servers can independently manage their share of the cache. This reduces contention and enhances performance in distributed applications.

In summary, the use of server names and hashing is a fundamental strategy in distributed caching to achieve both efficient data distribution and improved system scalability.